# Pattern to show related fields with Boolean value

Tags: forms, design-patterns

I am working on an application which show the employee's personal detail in a read only format. The form contains some fields which contains closely related fields where the answers are generally Yes or No. For example,

[image]

Any one here who has worked on similar lines where such answers can be shown in a visual manner. Problem area is that simple Yes and No answer here is taking up a lot of area and user really have to read through them just to have an idea.

Comment: If they are read only fields, then you should also consider a table going horizontally across the page if you can find good groupings for similarly related fields.

Answer (score 3):

How about an (red) "NO" icon or a (green) "Yes" icon to the left of each line? 
This way you save vertical space, but at least keep visual consistency (providing that you keep both icons the same width).

Is there any other solution, like filtering the results to only show the positives or negatives, if that is what the user is after? This way you'll minimize clutter and maximize your user's scanning performance.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to *group related, relevant* information together and leave out *mutually exclusive* items. As it is a read-only format there's not a lot of use in displaying the mutually exclusive **NO** answers (and possibly also some other **NO** answers).

I'd suppose that if **Veteran** is answered with **NO** all other Veteran related answers are obsolete and of no good use for the user, so you could just omit them.

Also e.g. *Special Disabled Veteran* and the *Other Disabled Veteran* items seem to be mutually exclusive, so there's not a lot of use to display the not selected one if there's no way to change it.

Answer (score 2):

How about just bolding the ones which are "YES" and others greyed out.

[image: Ideas to show related fields which signify boolean value]

Comment: This might lead to usability problems. Imagine a context where NO is the expected property. This representation would give no clue that YES is highlighted.

Comment: Then you rephrase the question so that YES is the expected answer? I hate when there is no consistency between expected answers. Yes should be used for a positive answer. ("Special disabled Veteran" isn't positive for the person, but it is a positive answer on the question)

Comment: Right, I see what you guys pointing to. I think @ajayashish can help us with the context . 

I assumed it is necessary to show all the options with their respective answers. May be showing a tick mark(✓) against bolded option to indicate **YES** and a cross mark(✗) to indicate **NO** for greyed options would solve the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just display the attributes which apply and hide the ones which do not. Makes the list easier to read and you don't have to worry about styling the thing extensively for readability. 
This does not apply if users really need to compare veterans against each other (are Joe and Dean both Vietnam veterans).